# Need to convert array with similar columns into single list with only 2 columns and remove blanks

Tags: arrays, excel-formula

I have an array of product use cases and columns for each feature--which creates an array of varying columns depending on the row

I want to convert to a single list of all features with a second column for the relevant product use case

I have an example attached---any tips for converting to a list?

Screenshot showing current state and ideal state with dummy data---actual data set is 50+ rows and 50+ columns

[image]

Comment: That depends on which version you have, but this would be better done with power query.  It can be done with formula in office 365.  If power query and office 365 are not options then vba will be you next best approach.

Answer (score 0):

This could be done by formula in Office 365:

```
=LET(data,B3:I7,
     r,ROWS(data),
     c,COLUMNS(data)-2, 
       first,INDEX(data,INT(SEQUENCE(r*c,,1,1/c)),1), 
       second,SUBSTITUTE(INDEX(data,INT(SEQUENCE(r*c,,1,1/c)),2+MOD(SEQUENCE(r*c,,0),c)+1),"",""),
     all,CHOOSE({1,2},first,IFERROR(--second,"")),
FILTER(all,INDEX(all,,2)<>""))
```

But using Power Query would be easier.